# Silverlight5 - Binding breakpoint not hit in ItemsControl

Tags: silverlight, xaml, visual-studio-2012

Using VS2012 and SL5.

When I set a breakpoint on the Content={Binding} and hit debug, the code works, but the breakpoint is never hit.  Why?

Have tried restarting studio (this works when I sometimes can't set a red dot breakpoint in code).

```
<Grid Grid.Row="5">
    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.Items>
            <Button Content="First" />
            <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" />
            <Button Content="Second" />
            <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" />
            <Button Content="Third" />
        </ItemsControl.Items>

        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate></ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why it didn't hit... no default binding has been setup.  This works below on the binding breakpoints.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="5">
    <!-- bind to the Data property of element AccountsDataSourceT32 -->
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=AccountsDataSourceT32}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate></ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding Username}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```